# How to post to a nested resource in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-resources, nested-routes, ruby-on-rails-4.1

I have a nested resource in my `routes.rb` file:

```
resources :users do
  resources :children
end
```

I have a form at `/users/:id/children/new`. Form comes up fine and the embedded ruby for the form looks like this:

```
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
```

Problem is I want this to submit to `/users/:id/children`, but it submits to `/users`. Is there a standard way this should be done in Rails?

Answer (score 1):

The embedded form shold look like this

```
<%= form_for [@user, Children.new] do |f|%>
 <%= f.label :children_attr,.....%>
  .
  .
```

see this [vedio](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JUL_7MNanPE), it might help.

Comment: hmm.. I don't have a `Children` model or a `Child` model. They are actually a `User` too. I just call the resource `children` because otherwise it would be `resources :users do; resources :users; end`